# Does anyone know why it happens? C++ 'initializing': cannot convert from

Tags: c++, arrays, class, object, debugging

So this is my header to a class:

```
#include <iostream>
class Board
{
public:
    Board();
    AllPieces* GetBoard();
    void createBoard();

protected:
    AllPieces** everything= new (AllPieces**)[32];

};
```

But when I try to initialize the 'everything' array, it says this error:

Error   C2440   'initializing': cannot convert from 'AllPieces ***' to 'AllPieces **'

I don't know why it says that, what I want to do is to make an array of pointers from the class AllPieces.

Can anybody help me please? thank you

Comment: `AllPieces** everything= new (AllPieces**)[32];` should be `AllPieces** everything= new AllPieces*[32];`

Comment: Related: Do forget everything related to double pointers. Use STL.

Comment: You better not use raw pointers and use smart pointers instdead. It will be much easier to manage.

Comment: Remember; more stars don't make you a better programmer - in fact, quite the opposite.

Answer (score 4):

The code `new (AllPieces**)[32]` creates a pointer to an object of type `AllPieces**`, which thus has a type of `AllPieces***`. If you drop one of the `*`, you will get the correct return type.

To eliminate the error, change the line in question to:

```
AllPieces** everything = new AllPieces*[32];
```

Comment: if I do so like this: AllPieces** everything= new (AllPieces*)[32]; there's a red line under the word new

Comment: @Heehee You need to lose the () just `new AllPieces*[32]`.